# Including a template html bit on a global page in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add a little vertical banner to  my magento store's theme. One that is `position: fixed;` and aligned `top: 50%; right: 0;` with the text rotated 90deg.

I'd like to have it setup via a cms block so I can change the text easier at a later date ([gist link](https://gist.github.com/Genesis2001/6109207) shows this). I'm unsure where / how to include this template onto my theme. My initial thought was to somehow include it into `page.xml`, specifically `page/html_footer` but I'm not even sure there. I'm very green when it comes to Magento.

My setup is shown in this [gist link](https://gist.github.com/Genesis2001/6109207) where I have a static block added via the Magento Admin Panel, a template that checks whether said block is enabled and displays itself, and a stub/mock of the layout xml.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue I see is your block type for your vertical banner, where you are using the type `page/html` - this is a block type in my experience typically reserved for one-time use (where all other blocks are a child of this one).

Try replacing this with the `core/template` block type.

One other note would be that you don't necessarily need a separate template to accomplish this.  If you simply use the `<block type="cms/block">` without the block wrapping this, you could then just call the banner from within your footer.phtml file using the same method as you would have in vertical-banner.phtml.  Hope this helps.